# Dialogue alerts within a pageReference

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I am working on a Visualforce button that calls an action in the extension.

```
<apex:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" action="{!submit}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');" />
```

If the user selects "OK", then the action evaluates for 3 scenarios. The first and second scenario should result in alerts.  The third scenario executes setting the value of a field to a value.  I would like to have an alert for the third scenario too to report "Submission successful."

How can I add alerts to my existing controller extension code (below)?  Thank you in advance!

```
    // Submit button
public PageReference submit() {
    string theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    if(theId == '' || theId == null) {
        return null;
    }

    for(Activity__c v : [SELECT Id, Required_Actions__c, Required_Issues__c FROM Activity__c WHERE Id =:theId]) {
        if(v.Required_Actions__c == TRUE) {
            return null;
            //window.alert('ERROR : Please document the actions before submitting.');
        }
        if(v.Required_Issues__c == TRUE) {
            return null;
            //window.alert('ERROR : Please document the issues before submitting.');
        }
        if(v.Required_Actions__c == FALSE && v.Required_Issues__c == FALSE) {
            activity.Locked__c = TRUE;
            update activity;
            //window.alert('Submission successful.');
        }

    }

    //Refresh the current Visualforce Page
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+theId);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `<apex:pageMessages />` to the Visualforce page and revised the extension to:

```
    // Submit button
public PageReference submit() {
    string theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    if(theId == '' || theId == null) {
        return null;
    }
    for(Activity__c v : [SELECT Id, Required_Actions__c, Required_Issues__c, Required_Fields__c FROM Activity__c WHERE Id =:theId]) {
        if(v.Required_Actions__c == TRUE && v.Required_Issues__c == FALSE) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please document the actions before submitting.'));
            return null;
        }
        if(v.Required_Actions__c == FALSE && v.Required_Issues__c == TRUE) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please document the issues before submitting.'));
            return null;
        }
        if(v.Required_Actions__c == TRUE && v.Required_Issues__c == TRUE) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please document the actions and issues before submitting.'));
            return null;
        }
        if(v.Required_Fields__c == FALSE) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Complete the assessment before submitting.'));
            return null;
        }
        if(v.Required_Actions__c == FALSE && v.Required_Issues__c == FALSE && v.Required_Fields__c == TRUE) {
            activity.Locked__c = TRUE;
            update activity;     
        }
    }       
    //Refresh the current Visualforce Page
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+theId);
    system.debug(pageRef);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);        
    return pageRef;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a string variable to the value of the alert message.

Then in the command button use `oncomplete="alert('{!MSG}');"`